# using between with apex item in Oracle apex_util.json_from_sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Does anybody know how to use apex item in apex_util.json_from_sql in application process when we try to find a value between two number? My query just like this one below :

```
SELECT  
ID , locn_x lat, locn_y lon
FROM database where locn_x between :P1_SEBOUNDLAT and :P1_NWBOUNDLAT
```

But it's return no result. Apex item :P1_SEBOUNDLAT and :P1_NWBOUNDLAT has a value cos i diplay it and i try to do query in database and give me result. it seem : without = become a problem in this query. Because when i try to query

```
where locn_x > :P1_SEBOUNDLAT
```

it give me an error

Please somebody give me an advice.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp it looks like i miss to pass addParam('x01' ... on ajax call, but my problem now, how i read the parameter value in query string?

Comment: sorry, I can't make any sense of that. *What error are you getting?*

Comment: @JeffreyKemp APEX_UTIL.JSON_FROM_SQL('SELECT  
ID ,locn_x lat, locn_y lon
FROM table where  locn_x between '||wwv_flow.g_x05||' and '||wwv_flow.g_x03|| )'); but i got error missing expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment you are executing this:

```
APEX_UTIL.JSON_FROM_SQL(
  'SELECT ID ,locn_x lat, locn_y lon FROM table where locn_x between '
|| wwv_flow.g_x05
|| ' and '
|| wwv_flow.g_x03
|| )');
```

And getting a "missing expression" error because of that last bit, which is missing a quote ('):

```
|| ')');
```

Comment: Thanx @JeffreyKemp it really help me alot, but can we use this " || " ? cause now it give another error  : Encountered the symbol "||" when expecting one of the following .... what i need to do is use variable inside select query with between in where clause.. thanx

Comment: Yap @Jeffreykemp , did i make this as answered question? or not?

Comment: Yes, that's what the green "tick" symbol means.